# Why does this C++ closure produce different outputs?

Tags: c++11, lambda, closures, c++14

I am trying to learn the concept of closures in C++. I have the following code.

```
std::function<void(void)> closureWrapper2()
{
    int x = 10;
    return [&x](){x += 1; std::cout << "Value in the closure: " << x << std::endl;};
}

int main()
{   
    std::function<void(void)> func2 = closureWrapper2();
    // std::cout << "---" << std::endl;
    func2();
    func2();
    func2();
}
```

**Output**

```
Value in the closure: 11
Value in the closure: 12
Value in the closure: 13
```

Now if I uncomment the `cout` statement I get the following output.

**Output**

```
---
Value in the closure: 32765
Value in the closure: 32766
Value in the closure: 32767
```

Can anyone please explain why printing something before the function calls changes the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
std::function<void(void)> closureWrapper2()
{
    int x = 10;
    return [&x](){x += 1; std::cout << "Value in the closure: " << x << std::endl;};
}
```

It's undefined behaviour<sup>(a)</sup> to dereference a pointer to, or use a reference to, an object after that object no longer exists. That's what you're doing here. You capture a *reference* to `x` then attempt to use it after `x` has ceased to exist.

It's a local (automatic storage duration) variable inside `closureWrapper2()` so ceases to exist when that function exits.

That may *appear* to work without the `cout` line but that doesn't make it any less undefined. Putting the `cout` line is almost certainly modifying the stack where `x` was originally stored, changing the starting value.

You can get a similar effect with (in my environment):

```cpp
void otherFn() { int abc = 97, def = 42, ghi = 9; std::cout << abc+def+ghi << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    std::function<void(void)> func2 = closureWrapper2();
    otherFn();
    func2();
    func2();
    func2();
}
```

This indicates that the original value is definitely being overwritten by the `abc` variable in `otherFn()`:

```
148
Value in the closure: 98
Value in the closure: 99
Value in the closure: 100
```

I had to try varying numbers of arguments as the stack frames for the `closureWrapper2()` and `otherFn()` are most likely different. Calling `cout.operator<<()` is likely to go through a *number* of stack levels to achieve its end so will be more likely to overwrite the original value.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is the solution to your problem, of course: don't do undefined behaviour :-)